# A person asks about networking but is using Linux Mint

Tags: discussion

So there's [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/603988/295286) question here, which is about wireless, but in the output of his script I can see that the person is using Linux Mint. I do know Mint is off topic here, but how should I deal with a question which isn't explicitly asks about Mint, but rather about one specific aspect of "ubuntu-ish" system ?

Answer (score 5):

Mint is off topic so as soon as someone tells you you vote to close.

My personal opinion: don't ask questions in comment that will lead to an answer that includes "mint" if it is not important and do not include "mint" in the question. If you do the only correct action should be "vote to close as off topic" and point them to the Mint help forum or U&L.

- The `cat /etc/lsb-release` should not have been included in the question.
- `uname -a` should not have been included in the question.

Both will have nothing to do with the problem.

Someone could remove these lines from the question. But I would also leave that to a mod to decide (he can decide to overrule the VTC and keep the question).

===

As Marco pointed out:  LinuxMint networking tool.

= 100% off topic.

===

Alternative: a mod can also move it to U&L.

Comment: So would it be appropriate for me to edit the question to remove those lines ? The particular one I linked is about network connection and network-manager

Comment: The person also is using the LinuxMint networking tool, there's really no way around this

Answer (score 4):

My personal approach would be:

If I would (have the feeling to-) know an answer on a question by someone using Mint, I would answer in a comment to be helpfull, but vote to close nevertheless.

You simply cannot decide whether an issue is related to Mint or not from a distance, and you should not bring yourself (or this site) in the position to have to discuss whether it is or not.

Answer (score 0):

from my opinion ... if you clearly not using mint tools (like ... the linuxmint updater or in this case, the network manager), I would still consider that Linux Mint is 'Ubuntu with some extra'.

I personally have not used any mint application (except mintMenu at MATE / GNOME2 Panel ... I love how it looks like Windoze), I just used mint because it already has MP3 support, Broadcom Wireless support (I just too lazy to do it on Ubuntu LOL), I hate the new GNOME, and for some reason I like green more than purple :P

What I've learned so far : do not tell if you are running mint. If you are clearly asking for help with mint tools, go ahead with StackExchange Unix. but if the problem is generally about ubuntu ... then do not mention the mint.